# Keycloak Proxy problems with jdk 1.8.0_16X

Tags: java, keycloak, jboss-tools

After upgrade java to 1.8.0_16X, Keycloak proxy stops to work. 
In particular when the browser try to create an SSL connection, the following exception occurs:

```
Exception in thread "XNIO-1 task-2" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: 
sun/security/ssl/SupportedEllipticPointFormatsExtension
at sun.security.ssl.HelloExtensions.<init>(HelloExtensions.java:84)
at sun.security.ssl.HandshakeMessage$ClientHello.<init>
(HandshakeMessage.java:245)
at sun.security.ssl.ServerHandshaker.processMessage(ServerHandshaker.java:224)
at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.processLoop(Handshaker.java:1052)
at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker$1.run(Handshaker.java:992)
at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker$1.run(Handshaker.java:989)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker$DelegatedTask.run(Handshaker.java:1467)
at io.undertow.protocols.ssl.SslConduit$5.run(SslConduit.java:1036)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

With java version 1.8.0_144 the proxy works corretly.

Please take a look into this issue and let me know if any suggestions.
Thank you.

**Environment Details**

Keycloak proxy: version 3.2.1 / 3.4.3 / 4.0.0

JDK version: Oracle 1.8.0_161/162

OS: Linux Ubuntu 16.04

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to Keycloak developers, Keycloak Proxy is no longer maintening. Switch to newer Keycloak Gatekeeper. (More details in [KEYCLOAK-7030](https://issues.jboss.org/browse/KEYCLOAK-7030))